# How to sort documents in mongoDB?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb

I have a collection like below

```
{
  _id: ObjectId('1asad23dsa45'),
  name: 'demo',
  addedOn: 1550228980162, // this is timestamp
},
{
  _id: ObjectId('12das34fda6'),
  name: 'demo2',
  addedOn: 1550228980156, // this is timestamp
},
{
  _id: ObjectId('12asd34fs6dfa'),
  name: 'demo3',
  addedOn: 1550228980160, // this is timestamp
}
```

I want to update all documents in such as way that all gets sorted by timestamp key

so after update the document may look like this

```
{
  _id: ObjectId('1asad23dsa45'),
  name: 'demo',
  addedOn: 1550228980162, // this is timestamp
},
{
  _id: ObjectId('12asd34fs6dfa'),
  name: 'demo3',
  addedOn: 1550228980160, // this is timestamp
},
{
  _id: ObjectId('12das34fda6'),
  name: 'demo2',
  addedOn: 1550228980156, // this is timestamp
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do what you are asking for. You cannot guarantee the order of updates while writing data.

However, you can always use [sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/) while reading data and preparing queries.

```
//Sort by descending
db.Collection.find().sort( { addedOn: -1 } )

//Sort by ascending
db.Collection.find().sort( { addedOn: 1 } )
```